# Page only in portrait

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm trying to have the index page of my app viewed only portrait. I've surfed the web but I didn't manage to find anything, except for `window.orientation` which it doesn't work to me. How can i do? I'm using Cordova (HTML, CSS and javascript). Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml file add/change this line in your global preferences .

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

Delete any existing orientation settings if there are any .

fyi. file location should be in following : app/www/config.xml according to:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref/

Comment: Will that work just for my index page and not for the other?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock orientation in a particular page use the following plugin link

http://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

So by using this plugin while loading page you can lock the orientation and while leaving or unloading the page you can unlock the orientation.